# How to create an index column with groupby in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
 tmp = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2018-08-31','2018-07-30','2018-07-30','2018-07-31']})
```

I would like to create a new column in the `tmp` dataframe, which will be an increasing index, starting from 1 for the minimum `date` and it will increase as the date increases.

The output dataframe should look like this:

```
         date  idx
0  2018-08-31    3
1  2018-07-30    1
2  2018-07-30    1
3  2018-07-31    2
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert column to datetimes, use [`Series.rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rank.html) and convert to integers:

```
tmp['date'] = pd.to_datetime(tmp['date'])
tmp['idx'] = tmp['date'].rank(method='dense').astype(int)
print (tmp)
        date  idx
0 2018-08-31    3
1 2018-07-30    1
2 2018-07-30    1
3 2018-07-31    2
```